# I am trying to run my flutter app and I am getting these errors?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk, version

here is the error message

The current Dart SDK version is 2.13.4.

Because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.8 requires SDK version >=2.10.0-0 <2.12.0 and test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.18 depends on typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0, test >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.18 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0.
And because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.18 <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 depends on test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 and test >=1.13.0 <1.14.5 depends on test_api 0.2.15, test >=1.13.0 <1.14.5-∞ or >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.15 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7.
And because test >=1.14.5 <1.15.0 depends on test_api 0.2.16 and test >=1.15.0 <1.15.3 depends on test_api 0.2.17, test >=1.13.0 <1.15.3-∞ or >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.15 or 0.2.16 or 0.2.17 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7.
And because test >=1.15.3 <1.15.5 depends on test_api 0.2.18 and test >=1.15.5 <1.16.0-nullsafety depends on test_api 0.2.18+1, test >=1.13.0 <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.15 or 0.2.16 or 0.2.17 or 0.2.18 or 0.2.18+1 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7.
And because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.19 <1.16.6 depends on test_api 0.2.19 and test >=1.18.0 requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, test >=1.13.0 <1.16.6-∞ or >=1.18.0 requires test_api 0.2.15 or 0.2.16 or 0.2.17 or 0.2.18 or 0.2.18+1 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or 0.2.19 or typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0.
And because every version of integration_test from sdk depends on both test_api 0.3.0 and typed_data 1.3.0, integration_test from sdk is incompatible with test >=1.13.0 <1.16.6-∞ or >=1.18.0.
And because test >=1.16.6 <1.18.0 depends on shelf_static ^1.0.0 which depends on convert ^3.0.0, if integration_test any from sdk and test >=1.13.0 then convert ^3.0.0.
And because flutter_svg 0.17.4 depends on xml ^3.3.1 which depends on convert ^2.1.0, one of integration_test any from sdk or test >=1.13.0 or flutter_svg 0.17.4 must be false.
And because no versions of flutter_svg match >0.17.4 <0.18.0 and test_ui depends on flutter_svg ^0.17.4, integration_test from sdk is incompatible with test >=1.13.0.
So, because test_ui depends on both integration_test any from sdk and test ^1.13.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because test_ui depends on both integration_test any from sdk and test ^1.13.0, version solving failed.)

can anyone help please?

here is my pubspec.yaml file

```yaml
name: test_ui
description: A new Flutter project.

    # The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
    # pub.dev using `pub publish`.This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

    # The following defines the version and build number for your application.
    # A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
    # followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
    # Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
    # build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
    # In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
    # Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
    # In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
    # Read more about iOS versioning at. 
 #https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

    # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
    # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  test: ^1.21.0

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

    # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
    # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
    # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

      # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/

    # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific 
   "variants", see
    # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

    # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
    # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

    # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
    # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
    # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
    # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
    # example:
    # fonts:
    #   - family: Schyler
    #     fonts:
    #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
    #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
    #         style: italic
    #   - family: Trajan Pro
    #     fonts:
    #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
    #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
    #         weight: 700
    #
    # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
    # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages`
```

Comment: can you show your pubspec.yaml your dependencies are depending on each other but are also out side the required version.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

Now Your dart sdk Current version:2.13.4

Please change your dart version 2.13.4 to 2.10.0.

Comment: please how can i do that cos i am not seeing any way to drop the version on the settings